# Spring application and Vault in docker-compose: how to init vault server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hashicorp-vault

I'm working on an application that should get some secrets from Vault.
I want the app to run on a container and the vault server on another one.
However I'm having some issues putting things together with docker-compose.

```
services:
   app:
       image: app/progettinotoy
       networks:
           - mainnet
       ports:
           - 8080:8080
       depends_on:
           - "vault"
           
       vault:
       image: vault
       cap_add:
           - "IPC_LOCK"
       networks:
           - mainnet
       ports:
           - 8200:8200
       environment: 
           VAULT_ADDR: http://127.0.0.1:8200
           VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG:
               api_addr = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
               cluster_addr = "https://127.0.0.1:8201"
               ui = true

               backend "file" {
                 path    = "/vault/file"
               }

               listener "tcp" {
                 address     = "0.0.0.0:8200"
                 tls_disable = "true"
               }
       command: 
           - "server"
        
   
networks:
   mainnet:
       driver: bridge
```

The main reason is that even though vault server is running, I should execute `vault operator init` and get root token and unseal keys before application starts to interact with vault server.
How can i do that?

Comment: Here's a complete docker-compose definition for local development with Vault on your dev machine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74347355/414544

After the Vault container is running, you can give the defined root token ("root" in the given example) to other services which need to communicate with the vault.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what happens to the data stored on `/vault/file`.

If the data is persistent (will it survive a restart)? If so, you should deploy Vault on its own and do a proper initialization ceremony.

If not (like an ephemeral test instance), run Vault in DEV mode with `server -dev --dev-root-token-id=asdf`, it will use `asdf` as the root token.